# getActivity() with in FragmentActivity: android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am using this class A which extends another abstract class (and this abstract class extends FragmentActivity) and in one of my function with in A class I want to get getActivity() for my current activity A. But whenever I use getActivity , It gives me error that getActivity() method is not defined type for my class. Please help me !! How can I achieve this??

Code for my class A

```
 public class A extends B
 {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.voicing);

    //doing another initializations and stuff//

   }
  }
```

code for class B

```
   public abstract class B extends FragmentActivity 
  {


   FragmentAdapter mAdapter;
   ViewPager mPager;
   PageIndicator mIndicator;


 }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `FragmentActivity` is an instance of `Activity` (in Java style: `FragmentActivity extends Activity`).

So there is no point calling `getActivity` because a `FragmentActivity` is already an `Acivity`, so just calling/using `this` will work. Also there is no method called `getActivity` in the `FragmentActivity` class. In other words your B class is extending an `Activity` instance.

So inside your A (or B) class you could use this code snippet to get the activity instance:

```
Activity test = (Activity) this;
```

But if your B class extends `Fragment` then the `getActivity` call would have worked.

Comment: Hey I am confuse here..I dont know for whom I should accept as answer...as I can accept only one answer..:)

Comment: Excellent post. It's so simple for some reason getActivity() wasn't working when I thought it should.

Answer (score 6):

`FragmentActivity` is an alternate to `Activity` in **support package**. Since your `class B` *extends* `FragmentActivity` and later your `class A` extends `class B`, therefore your `class A` is also referring `Activity` (a.k.a `FragmentActivity`).

In short, you dont need to call any method. simply use `this` keyword to refer to your activity instance.

Comment: Thanks a Lot!!!! It worked!!!..Sometime straight things seems complicated...Thanks a lot again!!!