# Actionbar menu item selection - token null is not for an application

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to use the menu item objects to set `onclick` listeners for each item. I keep getting a null pointer on the item selected. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId_ = item.getItemId();
    if (itemId_ == R.id.main_activity_actions_cancel) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setTitle("Exit Search Results?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Stop the activity
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No!", null)
                .show();
        return true;
    }
    else if (itemId_ == R.id.main_activity_actions_action_search) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        final EditText input = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        input.setHint("type here...");
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                start_searching_activity(value.trim());
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }
            return false;
}
```

Log:

```
 05-10 13:13:11.578  25113-25113/com.secret E/uncaught exception!!! android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:691)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:288)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:312)
            at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:991)
            at ads_swiped.secretsCardDealer.onOptionsItemSelected(secretsCardDealer.java:339)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3024)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:373)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1199)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:761)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:155)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:894)
            at android.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:611)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:180)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5197)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20909)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: what is line no 339 in secretsCardDealer.java?

Comment: line is: `alert.show();`

Comment: This is a FragmentActivity if that helps. Is this a context issue?

Comment: Oh yes..try replacing `getApplicationContext()` with `getActivity()`..you should pass the Activity, not the context for the AlertDialog.Builder..

Comment: I just did a `MyClass.this` and it worked! Would you like to post the answer?

Comment: Yes..thats what i said..`MyClass.this` returns your current activity..to make sure..just give a try with `getActivity()`

Comment: `getActivity()` method is not available in that spot for some reason

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693251/getactivity-with-in-fragmentactivity-android

Comment: yes yes..thank you for pointing out that..i'll update my answer..if my comments helped you kindly upvote my answer..

Comment: Yes thanks, i submitted an edit to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `getApplicationContext()` with `getActivity()` in

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

The `ApplicationContext` should not be used for tasks such as creating Dialogs. As you are in a fragment you can instead get the Activity-Context simply by calling the Fragments `getActivity()` method.

**UPDATE**

Since this is a FragmentActivity, you just need to call `this` to get the Activity.See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693251/getactivity-with-in-fragmentactivity-android) for more details.